# Namespaced callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have following scenario

Then I have function which checks following condition:

```
var callback = $input.data('callback');
if(callback){
     // I want to do something like this:
     window[callback].call(this);

 }
```

But I can't do that because of namespacing. What is best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Split callback on `'.'` and loop downward.

Comment: I think there should be some better way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split on `"."`, resolve each segment starting with window, and invoke with `()`:

```js
foo = {
  bar: {
    baz: function() {
      console.log("foo.bar.baz()");
    }
  }
};

"foo.bar.baz".split(".").reduce((o, n) => o[n], window)();
```

<sub>Note: For simplicity, I've used `Array.prototype.reduce()`. For older browsers, there's a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill) available.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
window.foo = {
    bar: function () {
        alert(this.val);
    },
    val: "foobar!"
}

var callback = "foo.bar";

if (callback) {
    var segments = callback.split('.'), 
        context = window;
    for (var i = 0; i < segments.length-1; i++) {
        context = context[segments[i]];
    }
    context[segments[i]]();
}​
```